# Connect linux to a raspberry Access Point, that no have internet connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot

I've setted a raspberry pi to act as an access point, for let communicate via tcp socket all the other devices connected at the same access point. So in this case i dont want that the access point let me access to internet! but if i try to connect from my ubuntu, the wifi manager detect that the AP has no internet connection, and doesnt mantain the connection with it! How can i solve this boring problem? thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network manager from ubuntu does maintain the connection even if there is no internet connection. But in the default configuration, a IPv4 address is required. You can either disable this check, give the connection a static IPV4 address or install a DHCP Server on the rasberry.